# as ... , so do(or to do?)

Tags: grammaticality

From [USADA RTP: The Notification Process | U.S. Anti-Doping Agency](https://www.usada.org/spirit-of-sport/education/usadas-registered-testing-pool-notification-process/):

> When athletes are added to USADA’s Registered Testing Pool, or RTP,
>   it’s usually because they are among the highest-performing athletes in
>   their sport, and **as** their performances increase, **so to do** their
>   anti-doping responsibilities.

Shouldn't it be *"so do"* instead of *"so to do"*?

Comment: No; that 'to' should be 'too'.

Comment: Although "so do" would be correct (and "so to do" is not), I think "so too do" is what was intended here.